# Detecting connected device fault to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot

I am able to send data from sensor to server using Raspberry Pi, but my aim is to find the devices (for example a sensor) connected to the Raspberry Pi using any language.

Comment: What do you mean? How the server will find out abou RPi's sensors? How code on the RPi itself will find out about the sensors?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at IoT frameworks and suites like those offered by Azure and Amazon and check how they handle telemetry and device management. Your question would make sense if you intend to develop software for arbitrary devices - otherwise you'd already know what's on the RPi. That's part of device management. Although you probably *shouldn't* allow the device to self-register its abilities for security reasons. Imagine a hacked device that started reporting sensor data for imaginary sensors

Comment: is there any method to find the sensor defect i mean how to detect that data is not comming from sensor??

Comment: there are multiple interfaces for sensors: 1-wire, i2c, spi, generic gpio.  driver will see malfunction or disconnect of your sensor unless you use generic gpio. What interface does your sensor use? - please extend your question with additional information